# How can I extract mean bioclimatic variables from unprojected grid cells?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, spatial

I have a shpfile from the [entire world](https://gadm.org/download_world.html) that I converted using the `as_Spatial()` function for compatibility with the sp package.

```
set.seed(27)
shp <- sf::st_read("earth_gadm.shp")
shape <- as_Spatial(shp)
```

As I am not working with any particular region, I assigned the `+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84` crs to my shpfile.

```
crs <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"
proj4string(shape) = crs
```

Following the [Matt Strimas-Mackei workflow](https://strimas.com/post/hexagonal-grids/) I used `spsample()` and `HexPoints2SpatialPolygons()` to create a hexagonal grid based on my shape object, and then I intersected the grid and the polygon.

```
size <- 2.5 #2.5 degrees as i am working with a latlong projection (correct?) 
hex_points <- spsample(shape, type = "hexagonal", cellsize = size) 
hex_grid <- HexPoints2SpatialPolygons(hex_points, dx = size)
shape.grid <- gIntersection(shape, hex_grid, byid = T)
```

I plotted some points on my new shapefile and overlaid them onto my shape.grid object.

```
library(rgbif)
gbif_data <- occ_data(scientificName = 'Lestes sponsa',
                      hasCoordinate = TRUE, limit = 60)
gbif_data <- gbif_data$data
coords <- gbif_data[ , c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude")]
coords$decimalLatitude <- as.numeric(coords$decimalLatitude)
coords$decimalLongitude <- as.numeric(coords$decimalLongitude)
coordinates(coords) <- ~decimalLongitude + decimalLatitude
coords <- data.frame(x = coords$decimalLongitude, y = coords$decimalLatitude)
coords <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords= coords, data = gbif_data)
proj4string(coords) = crs
x11()
plot(shape.grid, col = "grey50", bg = "light blue", axes = TRUE, cex = 20)
points(coords, col = 'blue', pch=20, cex = 0.75)
overlaid <- over(shape.grid, coords, returnList = T)
overlaid <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(overlaid), nrow=60, 
                        byrow=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

[image: plotted points]

Now I am trying to extract mean bioclimatic variables from the grid cells which have points plotted on. I also have 19 .bil rasters which I downloaded from [Wordclim](https://worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html). I was thinking in use these rasters to extract the bioclimatic variables. However, I am stuck at this step.

I tried:

```
bioclim_data <- extract(x=stackrasters, c(overlaid$decimalLongitude,                                      overlaid$decimalLatitude))
```

However, I am not sure if I am extracting mean values from the grid cells, and besides that only NA values are being returned with the above command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me if I'll only use similar datasets to demonstrate the workflow (gadm_410 is ~1.4 GB, wc2.1_30s_bio is ~ 9.7 GB). I'll also try to stick to `sf` and `terra` as much as possible:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.3.2, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(rgbif)

# I used the Admin 0 - Countries (1:10) dataset from Natural Earth 
shp <- sf::st_read("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp")
#> Reading layer `ne_10m_admin_0_countries' from data source 
#>   `ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 258 features and 168 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -180 ymin: -90 xmax: 180 ymax: 83.6341
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

# make hexagonal grid with res = 2.5° in WGS 84
grid <- sf::st_make_grid(shp,
                         cellsize = 2.5,
                         crs = 4326,
                         square = FALSE) |> sf::st_as_sf()

# get data
gbif_data <- occ_data(scientificName = 'Lestes sponsa',
                      hasCoordinate = TRUE, 
                      limit = 60)
gbif_data <- gbif_data$data

# create a simple features object from your data
data_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(gbif_data, 
                        coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), 
                        crs = sf::st_crs(4326))

# select objects from grid (= cells) containing points from data_sf (= locations)
grid_subset <- sf::st_filter(grid, data_sf)
```

Almost finished, you only have to import your raster data and make use of `terra::extract()` to get your desired values:

```r
library(terra)

# I used wc2.1_30s_prec from WorldClim, read using `rast()`
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.tif")
prec <- terra::rast(files)

# note that the resulting SpatRast object has 12 layers
prec
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> sources     : wc2.1_30s_prec_01.tif  
#>               wc2.1_30s_prec_02.tif  
#>               wc2.1_30s_prec_03.tif  
#>               ... and 9 more source(s)
#> names       : wc2.1~ec_01, wc2.1~ec_02, wc2.1~ec_03, wc2.1~ec_04, wc2.1~ec_05, wc2.1~ec_06, ... 
#> min values  :           0,           0,           0,           0,           0,           0, ... 
#> max values  :         973,        1309,        1145,        1049,        2081,        2226, ... 

# extract values from prec by polygons from grid_subset using mean as aggregate
results <- terra::extract(prec, terra::vect(grid_subset), fun = mean)

# prec has 12 layers, grid_subset consists of 60 polygons, 
# c.f. dimensions below (+ID column containing an identifier of the related polygon)
str(results)
#> 'data.frame':    60 obs. of  13 variables:
#>  $ ID               : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_01: num  74 70 70 70 70 70 70 67 67 67 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_02: num  65 51 51 51 51 51 51 52 52 52 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_03: num  52 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_04: num  51 46 46 46 46 46 46 45 45 45 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_05: num  61 62 62 62 62 62 62 61 61 61 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_06: num  46 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_07: num  42 70 70 70 70 70 70 66 66 66 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_08: num  43 60 60 60 60 60 60 57 57 57 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_09: num  62 72 72 72 72 72 72 67 67 67 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_10: num  68 71 71 71 71 71 71 66 66 66 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_11: num  75 79 79 79 79 79 79 72 72 72 ...
#>  $ wc2.1_30s_prec_12: num  77 77 77 77 77 77 77 73 73 73 ...
```

Sorry if I did not really answer your question and dared to project your grid cells.. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the sf::st_filter() function isnt working. I keep getting the following error: 

Error in `stopifnot()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = lengths(.predicate(x, y, ...)) > 0`.
Caused by error in `st_geos_binop()`:
! st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

I tried to assign the same CRS for both grid and data_sf objects, however the error message kept popping up.

Could you help me with this issue? Thanks again :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Somehow this error did not appear when I was writing an answer. Seems like the reason is: `bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data`. If you check the extent of the grid via `st_bbox(grid)`, you'll notice the invalid range right away. Unfortunately, `st_crop()` and `st_intersection()` seem not to be working because of this. The reason for this: `shp` is already using the valid bbox range completely. Hence, when creating a global hexagonal grid, there is some overshooting. This should not be the case with orthogonal grids (`square = TRUE`).

Comment: Or you might want to create a grid of a smaller extent, not covering the globe and producing artifacts at the margins, but at your regional scale, i.e. calling `sf::st_make_grid()` not on `shp`, but on `sf_data`.

Comment: It worked with with orthogonal grids. Thanks :)

Comment: May i ask you another question? when dealing with points with same coordinate, these are omitted when I extract() variables from grid cells, i.e., only one value is returned. Is it possible to make a new column in the dataframe with my original points (some of them with equal coordinate) and the value I extracted from the grid cell? I tried to summarize this question here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438644/extracting-variables-from-grid-cells-using-r

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract mean values from the grid cells, you need to use the grid cell polygons rather than point coordinates. Instead of using 'over', you can simply select the polygons that overlay points, and then extract the mean raster values for those polygons. Something like this:

```
shape.grid.containing.points <- shape.grid[coords, ]

plot(shape.grid.containing.points)

bioclim_data <- extract(x=stackrasters, y=shape.grid.containing.points, fun=mean)
```

Note also that GBIF data normally need to be cleaned, and that you shouldn't assign a CRS to a spatial object that already has its CRS, like the GADM map. And you eventually will need to migrate your spatial code e.g. to 'terra', as 'sp' will be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, your commands worked very well :) But, I'm still having one little problem. And It would be great if you could help me. 

I am trying to extract() variables from ~700 points, and several of them have the same coordinate. And following your commands I only get one value for these repeated coordinates (i.e., the value of the grid cell). 

However, I would like to have the values appearing for all points (and have 700 lines in the data frame), even though I am extracting variables from individual grid cells.   

Could you help me with this little problem? 

Thanks.